# jBPM timer is not running

Tags: jbpm

I have the following timer implementation:

```
<task-node name="recenze" create-tasks="false">
    <event type="node-enter" >
        <action expression="#{assignActors.assignActors(vybraniUzivatele,'recenze')}"></action>
    </event>

    <timer name="trolololo" duedate="5 business seconds" transition="transitionToVyporadaniPripominek" />

    <task name="recenze" description="A003: Ustanovení recenzentů" />

    <transition name="transitionToVyporadaniPripominek" to="vyporadaniPripominek" />
</task-node>
```

I tried to find wehere is the issue but I failed. The timer declaration seems correct according to many sources on the internet. In `jbpm_job` jBPM table there is job started by my timer with all its information set correrctly. But the timer do not trigger.

Does anyone know where can be the issue here? Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

Cahnge highlighted create-task flag from false to true and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting a code of my BPMN file which i used to understand the timer concept in JBPM hope that it would be Helpful to you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
             <definitions id="Definition"
             targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/MinimalExample"
             typeLanguage="http://www.java.com/javaTypes"
             expressionLanguage="http://www.mvel.org/2.0"
             xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd"
             xmlns:g="http://www.jboss.org/drools/flow/gpd"
             xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
             xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
             xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.jboss.org/drools">




 <process processType="Private" isExecutable="true" id="TimerBoundaryEventTest"                                                                                                                                                                                                    name="Timer Boundary Event Test" tns:packageName="defaultPackage" >



         <!-- nodes -->
        <startEvent id="_1" name="StartProcess" />
        <subProcess id="_2" name="SubProcess"  >
        <!-- nodes -->
        <startEvent id="_2-1" name="StartSubProcess" />
        <endEvent id="_2-3" name="EscalationEvent" />
        <scriptTask id="_2-4" name="Script" scriptFormat="http://www.java.com/java" >
          <script>System.out.println("In Script Task");
           Thread.sleep(6000);
            System.out.println("In Script Task After Sleep");
            Thread.sleep(2000);</script>
        </scriptTask>
        <!-- connections -->
        <sequenceFlow id="_2-4-_2-3" sourceRef="_2-4" targetRef="_2-3" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_2-1-_2-4" sourceRef="_2-1" targetRef="_2-4" />
        </subProcess>
        <endEvent id="_3" name="EndProcess" >
            <terminateEventDefinition/>
        </endEvent>
        <boundaryEvent id="_4" name="TimerEvent" attachedToRef="_2" >
          <timerEventDefinition>
            <timeDuration xsi:type="tFormalExpression">500ms</timeDuration>
          </timerEventDefinition>
        </boundaryEvent>
        <scriptTask id="_5" name="Goodbye" >
          <script>System.out.println("Timer handled");</script>
        </scriptTask>
        <endEvent id="_6" name="EndProcess" >
            <terminateEventDefinition/>
        </endEvent>
        <intermediateCatchEvent id="_7" name="Timer" >
          <timerEventDefinition>
            <timeCycle xsi:type="tFormalExpression">2000###2000</timeCycle>
          </timerEventDefinition>
        </intermediateCatchEvent>

        <!-- connections -->
        <sequenceFlow id="_1-_2" sourceRef="_1" targetRef="_2" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_7-_3" sourceRef="_7" targetRef="_3" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_4-_5" sourceRef="_4" targetRef="_5" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_5-_6" sourceRef="_5" targetRef="_6" />
        <sequenceFlow id="_2-_7" sourceRef="_2" targetRef="_7" />

      </process>

      <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="TimerBoundaryEventTest" >
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_1" >
            <dc:Bounds x="16" y="85" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_2" >
            <dc:Bounds x="96" y="16" width="223" height="187" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_2-1" >
            <dc:Bounds x="115" y="62" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_2-3" >
            <dc:Bounds x="205" y="132" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_2-4" >
            <dc:Bounds x="190" y="63" width="80" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_3" >
            <dc:Bounds x="431" y="85" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_4" >
            <dc:Bounds x="16" y="235" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_5" >
            <dc:Bounds x="96" y="235" width="223" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_6" >
            <dc:Bounds x="351" y="235" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="_7" >
            <dc:Bounds x="351" y="85" width="48" height="48" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_2-4-_2-3" >
            <di:waypoint x="134" y="71" />
            <di:waypoint x="133" y="140" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_2-1-_2-4" >
            <di:waypoint x="43" y="70" />
            <di:waypoint x="134" y="71" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_1-_2" >
            <di:waypoint x="40" y="109" />
            <di:waypoint x="207" y="109" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_7-_3" >
            <di:waypoint x="375" y="109" />
            <di:waypoint x="455" y="109" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_4-_5" >
            <di:waypoint x="40" y="259" />
            <di:waypoint x="207" y="259" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_5-_6" >
            <di:waypoint x="207" y="259" />
            <di:waypoint x="375" y="259" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_2-_7" >
            <di:waypoint x="207" y="109" />
            <di:waypoint x="375" y="109" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
        </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
      </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>

    </definitions>
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using session per process instance ? If yes then whenever a safe point comes all data related to that process instance is persisted in db along with session information and the session is cleared out from memory. Now u r timer was scheduled with that session and when u come back and restore the session now u have to link ur timer again to that session to be loaded in memory and schedulled as a job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I declare my timer, exactly like a previous answer example:

```
<boundaryEvent id="_ID" name="TimerEvent" attachedToRef="_ANOTHERID" >
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeCycle xsi:type="tFormalExpression">500ms</timeCycle>
      </timerEventDefinition>
</boundaryEvent>
```

The difference is I do not use threads or intermediate catch events....that boundary event, associated with a given process, is enough to trigger the timer and cause the wait-state. This has been tested and works properly.

Hope it helps :)